# SMTP Server software above Windows 2008 SMTP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

i need some software which has more functionality than regular Windows built-in SMTP server. What i'm interested in mainly is fine looking logs of successes versus failures and email scheduling.

Is there any of these that you know of?

Please avoid answers like "there is Linux x that does that" or use command line utilities to get logs.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at Mercury/32. The logging is very straight forward. The emailing scheduling may be its one weaker ability.